# Sql server lock like in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Is there a way to perform a lock on an object level in sql server similar to how the lock keyword works in c# so that when multiple connections call a stored procedure the procedure is executed sequentially for each client and not in parallel?

Comment: Like table/page/row locking? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Comment: Separate, I want a lock that is shared across some stored procedures but leaves the tables as they are